# how to protect software with dongle usb and where can I buy it?

Tags: security, dongle

I worked on a project for 9 months and I am finally ready to start selling it to potential clients. Before I do this, I would like to know what security measures to take so that it doesn't get hacked or stolen by pirates.

i want to secure my soft with this two conditions:

1/ check if the dongle is exist on the user pc
2/ if the dongle exist, check if the user is connected to the internet

and i want to host all the software scripts in the server ( encrypted )

my question is :

i don't have any idea about the dongle protection
is i can to turn any usb flash disk to dongle ? or i must to buy it ?

Comment: Dongles are user hostile, I suspect you will loose more potential customers than potential pirate losses.

Comment: You can’t use a thumb drive. Whatever you stored in one would be copyable.

Comment: How does having the "software scripts" (whatever that means) encrypted on the server help, where is the encryption key, on the server? Assume an attacker will gain admin access to the server.

Comment: @zaph i must to do this :(
of course the encryption key inside the soft, but before starting my software i want to upload the whole script to my server and compare it to the original script ... if there is any change .. the soft not start or i will block the user

Am I correct ? can you tell me any idea to secure my soft
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Verifying authenticity of the scripts.

It is not necessary to upload the whole script to the server just to verify it is un-changed, that is what hashes are for.

1. Create hashes of all the scripts and save them on the server.
2. Have the client create a hash of the script and upload that to the server.
3. On the server compare the client hash with the server hash.

Note: Just about any cryptographic hash can be used, SHA-256 is a good choice, is only 32-bytes and generally quite fast.

Alternatively you could compare the hash on the client. If you are concerned with a user changing the comparison hashes in the client it is more likely the user will just remove the scrypt check. This is essentially what Apple does, it has hashes of all code files as part of the application (with a few special things).

Flash drive as a dongle: No that will notwork because a user can just duplicate the flash drive.